# Pysnmp Error:NotInTimeWindow

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysnmp

When I collect data from a device via pysnmp, I encounter NotInTimeWindow error.

I can use snmpget to get the data, though. So I am wondering how could I resolve this issue?

Python:

```
next(
    snmpEngine,
    UsmUserData('pduaccess'),
    UdpTransportTarget(('10.232.69.200',161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.2769.1.4.1.21.0'))
)
# -> (NotInTimeWindow(), 0, 0, [])
```

snmpget tool:

```
snmpget -v3 -u pduaccess 10.232.69.200 1.3.6.1.4.1.2769.1.4.1.21.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2769.1.4.1.21.0 = STRING: "V2.07 - 08.11.2016"
```

Comment: Which pysnmp version are you using? Make sure to run the latest as there might  be relevant bugs and fixes to pysnmp in the past.

Comment: Can you share the actual error message?  Or is it just the `# -> (NotInTimeWindow(), 0, 0, [])`?

Answer (score 0):

PySNMP 4.4.x does not work very well with other SNMP implementations, as it failed to sync time data, as detailed [in a bug](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/issues/5).

Your code uses noAuthNoPriv mode, which suffers [another bug](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/issues/6).

Currently only `pysnmp-lextudio` >= 5.0.24 contains both patches to resolve the bugs.